# How to read S3 object response body

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, multipartform-data, pcf

I uploaded a file/csv to my Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) ECS S3 storage. Which was created successfully.

```
import requests

url = "https://host/bucket/test.csv"

payload = {}
files = [
  ('file-name', open('test.csv','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'X-Amz-Date': '20200622T112852Z',
  'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=cred_endpoint, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=sigV4'
}

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

When I try to access it I get a response like this

```
GET https://host/bucket/test.csv Status Code - 200

----------------------------017095580637364775189995
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-name"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

rank,name
1,Michael
2,Jim
3,Dwight
----------------------------017095580637364775189995--
```

Which is the correct data but it's in this weird format with boundaries in the body, what would be the most robust way to read this kind of response body and generate the exact same or similar file/csv as the one upload?

Also am I even doing this correctly? Because all the docs imply there should be a `[181(whatever the file size) bytes of object data]` in the body instead of the actual content of the file.

Comment: I would recommend using `boto3`, which is the AWS SDK for Python. You can just use an [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) command.

Comment: The issue is I am using a PCF ECS S3 storage not AWS S3. And I tried to configure `boto3` for it but couldn't.

Comment: Oh! I thought you were referring to Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS)! In that case... no idea!